# My removeButton is not working at first when i run the application

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

So the remove closure that i created works and all but it was a problem at first without moving the page it goes trough the function but the closure doesn't work.

```
var removeCell: ((SneakersTableCell) -> ())?
    var customView = CustomViewModel()
    var viewModel = Sneakers()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .default,reuseIdentifier: "SneakersTableCell")
        print("New cell has been create")
        setupUI()
        setupConstraints()
        removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        wishButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func removeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped remove button")
        removeCell?(self)
    }
```

This is the part done in the UITableViewCell

```
 extension CustomTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return viewModel.sneakersClass.cart.count + 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case viewModel.sneakersClass.cart.count:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier(for: .orderSummary)) as? OrderSummaryCell else {
                fatalError("Unable to dequeue OrderSummaryView cell")
            }
            return cell
        default:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier(for: .sneakers)) as? SneakersTableCell else {
                fatalError("Unable to dequeue SneakersTableCell cell")
            }
            let product = viewModel.sneakersClass.cart[indexPath.row]
            cell.configure(product: product)
            cell.qtyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openModal(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.removeCell = { [weak self] aCell in
                guard let self = self,
                      let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: aCell),
                      let summaryCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.viewModel.sneakersClass.cart.count, section: 0)) as? OrderSummaryCell
                else { return }
                self.viewModel.sneakersClass.cart.remove(at: idxPath.row)
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [idxPath], with: .automatic)
                summaryCell.updateSummaryValues(viewModel: self.viewModel)
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    @objc func openModal(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let modalViewController = ModalConfigurator().build(type: .quantity, gender: .women)
        modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(modalViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The code that follows is relative to my tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

final class SneakersTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    private let productImageView = UIImageView()
    private let categoryLabel = UILabel()
    private let nameLabel = UILabel()
    private let priceLabel = UILabel()
    private let sizeLabel = UILabel()
    private let colorLabel = UILabel()
    let removeButton = UIButton()
    private let clearImage = UIImage(systemName: "xmark")?.withTintColor(.label, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    var qtyButton = UIButton()
    private let arrowQty = UIImage(named: "Arrow_Qty")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    private let wishButton = UIButton()
    
    var removeCell: ((SneakersTableCell) -> ())?
    var customView = CustomViewModel()
    var viewModel = Sneakers()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .default,reuseIdentifier: "SneakersTableCell")
        print("New cell has been create")
        setupUI()
        setupConstraints()
        removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        wishButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func removeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped remove button")
        removeCell?(self)
    }
    
    @objc func wishButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Moved to wishlist")
    }

    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(product: Product) {
        productImageView.image = product.image
        categoryLabel.text = product.category
        nameLabel.text = product.name
        priceLabel.text = "\(product.price)€"
        sizeLabel.text = "Size: \(product.size)"
        colorLabel.text = "Color: \(product.color)"
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        selectionStyle = .none
        
        let array = [productImageView,
                     categoryLabel,
                     nameLabel,
                     priceLabel,
                     sizeLabel,
                     colorLabel,
                     removeButton,
                     qtyButton,
                     wishButton]
        
        array.forEach { view in
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(view)
        }
        
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        
        categoryLabel.font = FontStyle.uiS.baseUIFont
        categoryLabel.textColor = Color.grayScale400
        
        nameLabel.font = FontStyle.displayMBold.baseUIFont
        nameLabel.textColor = Color.grayScale700
        
        priceLabel.font = FontStyle.uiS.baseUIFont
        priceLabel.textColor = Color.grayScale700
        
        sizeLabel.font = FontStyle.uiXS.baseUIFont
        sizeLabel.textColor = Color.grayScale700
        
        colorLabel.font = FontStyle.uiXS.baseUIFont
        colorLabel.textColor = Color.grayScale700
        
        removeButton.setImage(clearImage, for: .normal)
        
        qtyButton.setTitle("Qty: 1 ", for: .normal)
        qtyButton.setImage(arrowQty, for: .normal)
        qtyButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        qtyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        qtyButton.backgroundColor = Color.grayScaleWhite
        qtyButton.setTitleColor(Color.grayScale700, for: .normal)
        qtyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        qtyButton.layer.borderColor = Color.grayScale200?.cgColor
        qtyButton.titleLabel?.font = FontStyle.uiM.baseUIFont
        qtyButton.tintColor = Color.grayScale700
        
        wishButton.setTitle("Move to wishlist", for: .normal)
        wishButton.setTitleColor(Color.grayScale700, for: .normal)
        wishButton.titleLabel?.font = FontStyle.uiM.baseUIFont
        
        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Move to wishlist", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        wishButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 274),
            
            productImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 32),
            productImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            productImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 106),
            productImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 114),
            
            categoryLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.topAnchor, constant: 18),
            categoryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 159),
            nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            
            priceLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            priceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            priceLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56),
            priceLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14),
            
            sizeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            sizeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            sizeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46),
            sizeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            
            colorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            colorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sizeLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            colorLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62),
            colorLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            
            removeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.topAnchor),
            removeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor,constant: -24),
            removeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            removeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            
            qtyButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            qtyButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            qtyButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant:20),
            qtyButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 106),
            qtyButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64),
            
            wishButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: qtyButton.centerYAnchor),
            wishButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant:-20),
            wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 116),
            wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
        ])
    }
}
```

This one is in a TableView inside the cellForRowAt method.
Can you help me find the problem?

When i first start the application the remove function works but not the closure

[First!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPXvC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView`’s `cellForRow:at:` will return nil if that row is not visible, pre-fetched or cached. So your guard statement will return if that cell has not yet been fetched from the data source. This explains why your delete closure works once you scroll the table far enough for the summary cell to be fetched (it may be pre-fetched, it isn’t necessarily visible yet).

Your code should separately handle the summary row and do nothing if the cell cannot be found:

```
cell.removeCell = { [weak self] aCell in
    guard let self = self,
          let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: aCell)
    else { return }
    
    // This is optional and will be nil if the cell is not visible (or pre-fetched, or cached)
    // We get this before deleting the item as the delete will adjust `count` 
    let summaryCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.viewModel.sneakersClass.cart.count, section: 0)) as? OrderSummaryCell
    
    self.viewModel.sneakersClass.cart.remove(at: idxPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [idxPath], with: .automatic)

    // Now the item has been deleted we can update the summary cell (if we have one)
    summaryCell?.updateSummaryValues(viewModel: self.viewModel)

}
```

Comment: it is working good now but the values on ordersummary just update the second time i remove

Comment: Your summary row might be getting pre-fetched before it is needed and, I guess, `cellForRow:at:` in the data source is configuring it with data that was valid at the time. But before the cell is actually visible you delete something else. The summary cell will not be fetched again in this scenario so will have stale data. You may need to refresh the order summary cell just before it becomes visible: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

Comment: Still not working i cant manage to put that function working since I have never seen it before

Comment: Can you please add your code for the table view data source that configures the cells (add it to the question, not as a comment).

Comment: Oh, I just thought of a possible problem with my answer. My code is updating the summary cell before deleting the row, so it will be “one behind” all the time. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Still does doesnt update at first its updating the price right but after the second remove only. And i´ve added the code relative to the cell

Comment: You haven’t added code for how the table view data source configures the cell. I mean the table view data source method that dequeues a cell and calls the `updateSummaryValues` method when the summary cell is fetched.

Comment: the code that dequeues the cell is there now i think so at least

Comment: Thank you. As I suspected, you are not configuring the summary cell when it is first created. The `cellForRowAt` method also needs to call `updateSummaryValues` so that it will have correct data the first time it is created. If there are more products then fit on screen (and depending on what pre-fetching happens) the first time you delete a product there will not be a summary cell. When it is scrolled into view, the table view delegate is responsible for initialising its contents.

Comment: so how i am supposed to make that call?

Comment: Your code in `cellForRow:atIndex` has a case for returning an `OrderSummaryCell` which it the just returns. Simple call the `updateSummaryValues` method on the cell before returning it. I cannot understand how the summary cell ever showed correct information without this (until it had been dequeued and then it was updated by deleting an item).

Comment: Another thing do you know about MVVM enough so you can help me pass it to MVVM?

Comment: You already have a view model. I cannot afford to spend more time helping you, sorry.